# Disk Space Full

Tags: server, disk-usage

Setting up Ubuntu 10.04 server,  the / disk space shows full under df, however the du does not show any of the space used.  This has several mounts to Gluster FS'.

I have tried a forced FSCK and to no avail.

```
~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0              141G  132G     0 100% /
none                  3.0G  224K  3.0G   1% /dev
none                  3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev/shm
none                  3.0G   76K  3.0G   1% /var/run
none                  3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /var/lock
none                  3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /lib/init/rw
```

I've attempted a tune2fs and same issue arises

```
# du -h --max-depth=1 --one-file-system /
4.0K    /selinux
0   /proc
47M /boot
31M /mnt
8.0K    /brick1
8.0K    /brick2
391M    /lib
4.0K    /opt
7.4M    /bin
0   /sys
379M    /var
5.6M    /etc
16K /lost+found
43M /root
4.0K    /srv
5.7M    /home
4.0K    /media
7.0M    /sbin
0   /dev
4.0K    /tmp
4.0K    /cdrom
631M    /usr
1.6G    /
```

more info

```
# df -ih
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md0                9.0M     91K    8.9M    1% /
none                    746K     770    745K    1% /dev
none                    747K       1    747K    1% /dev/shm
none                    747K      32    747K    1% /var/run
none                    747K       1    747K    1% /var/lock
none                    747K       3    747K    1% /lib/init/rw
localhost:/sanvol09      25G     76M     25G    1% /mnt/sanvol09
```

The final question: df show's 100% used, and its not, any other known fixes?

tune2fs

```
:~# tune2fs -l /dev/md0
tune2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          a94d2b93-35f8-4b59-81f1-38bf48833d0c
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              9371648
Block count:              37475824
Reserved block count:     3747582
Free blocks:              2374280
Free inodes:              9304627
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1015
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
RAID stride:              1
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Oct 16 17:41:02 2012
Last mount time:          Tue Nov 27 11:51:07 2012
Last write time:          Tue Dec  4 08:54:43 2012
Mount count:              3
Maximum mount count:      34
Last checked:             Tue Nov 27 10:08:25 2012
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Sun May 26 10:08:25 2013
Lifetime writes:          24 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1048583
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      6dc653fe-dd10-46b6-8c7d-a6a292e92ea9
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Comment: What's your question?  I don't see anything asked here...

Comment: Maybe he wants to know what's using his space?

Comment: What does `df -i` show?

Comment: Added the requested info

Comment: you have more than 2 tb

Comment: run `du` with `sudo`.

Comment: Running as root, but attempted sudo 
1.5G /

Comment: What file system are you running on `/dev/md0`? I mean the file system under GlusterFS. XFS, Ext3/Ext4, etc. In case of Ext, the 'Reserved block count' might cause trouble here. Inspect with `tune2fs -l /dev/md0`.

Comment: ext3 

I've added the results from the command above

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Here solution for you, please umount /mnt/sanvol09 and check the original folder. Maybe before mounting it you had files in that folder. After mounting it you wont be able to see them. So go ahead umount, cleanup that folder and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for open files (files which are deleted while still in use by any process) using following tools

`lsof | sort -nrk 7,7 | head -20` and `df -h /` and `du -x -sh /`

In lsof output you can see keyword deleted for deleted files. For Example

```
root@demobox:/root : lsof | grep -i deleted
dsmcad    25449       root  txt       REG              253,0  4843037     459377 /opt/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin/dsmcad (deleted)
root@demobox:/root : ls -l /opt/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin/dsmcad
ls: cannot access /opt/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin/dsmcad: No such file or directory
```